# Can't set Rx variable because runtimeType is different

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, revenuecat

I have a GetX app and I want to sync the CustomerInfo from Revenuecat with my app (I wasn't sure if this information is necessary so I included it). I basically add a listener to do this:

```dart
Purchases.addCustomerInfoUpdateListener((CustomerInfo info) {
  print(info.runtimeType);
  customerInfo.value = info;
});
```

The type of
customerInfo is a Rx variable on my GetX controller that looks like this: `Rx<CustomerInfo?> customerInfo = null.obs;`.
But this doesn't work, because the runtimeType of `ìnfo` is `_$CustomerInfoImpl` and not `CustomerInfo`. I tried casting the value but that doesn't work either. I always get this error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type '_$CustomerInfoImpl' is not a subtype of type 'Null' of 'v'
#0      RxObjectMixin.call (package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_core/rx_impl.dart:62:14)
#1      AccountController.onInit.<anonymous closure> (package:mitt_sjo_liv/controllers/account_controller.dart:311:19)
#2      Purchases.addCustomerInfoUpdateListener (package:purchases_flutter/purchases_flutter.dart:191:33)
#3      AccountController.onInit (package:mitt_sjo_liv/controllers/account_controller.dart:308:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same problem, I found a solution:
Instead of using `Rx<CustomerInfo?>`, you have to use `Rxn<CustomerInfo>`.